# pandas: divide selected rows by a number

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
    Rounds  Metrics         WA_All_par_1
1   0       Time(minutes)   27.390000
2   0       Score           0.027585
3   1       Time(minutes)   47.390000
4   1       Score           0.228589
5   2       Time(minutes)   137.390000
6   2       Score           0.428589
```

I want to divide the rows by 60 where Metrics column is **Time(minutes)**, without disturbing other rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df.loc[
    df['Metrics'].eq('Time(minutes)'), 'WA_All_par_1'
] = df['WA_All_par_1'] / 60
```

or with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df['WA_All_par_1'] = np.where(df['Metrics'].eq('Time(minutes)'),
                              df['WA_All_par_1'] / 60, 
                              df['WA_All_par_1'])
```

Or with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```
df['WA_All_par_1'] = df['WA_All_par_1'].where(df['Metrics'].eq('Time(minutes)'),
                                              df['WA_All_par_1'] / 60)
```

```
   Rounds        Metrics  WA_All_par_1
0       0  Time(minutes)      0.456500
1       0          Score      0.027585
2       1  Time(minutes)      0.789833
3       1          Score      0.228589
4       2  Time(minutes)      2.289833
5       2          Score      0.428589
```

---

Also consider replacing the units with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace):

```
df['Metrics'] = df['Metrics'].str.replace('minutes', 'hours', regex=True)
```

```
   Rounds      Metrics  WA_All_par_1
0       0  Time(hours)      0.456500
1       0        Score      0.027585
2       1  Time(hours)      0.789833
3       1        Score      0.228589
4       2  Time(hours)      2.289833
5       2        Score      0.428589
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
        
df['WA_All_par_1'] = np.where(df['Metrics'].str.contains('minutes'), \
  df['WA_All_par_1'].div(60), df['WA_All_par_1'])
```

I used Numpy `where()` to distinguish rows based on whether the cell contains the string "minutes" anwhere in the text. Then I return the division result when the condition is True.